# Create view on Azure SQL Server that reads table from onpremise SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure

I wonder if its possible to create a view on Azure SQL Server that reads a table of an onpremise SQL Server. Data sync will not be a live view on the local data so this would not be an option.

Best regards

Lars

Comment: As I know, you cannot create a Linked Server from Azure to a local instance. The other way around yes.

Comment: You might want to look into [SQL Server Stretch Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-server-stretch-database/).  This isn't exactly what you are asking for, but it does mix on-prem and Azure.